# Indirect Jump ByteCode

Tags: ethereum, bytecode, solidity, evm, etherscan

I am trying to understand Ethereum Bytecodes. So whenever there is any JUMP/JUMPI opcode it is preceded by some PUSH opcode.

My question is how can I differentiate if this jump is direct or indirect?
Can someone provide me some example of Ethereum bytecodes where jump is Indirect.

Answer (score 0):

When it jumps to a label, it's indirect by definition. And when it jumps to an absolute value, it's direct again by definition.

Comment: I guess push is not there for indirect jump because if push is there before jump then the target address is directly sitting on the top of the stack.